# How do I populate a dropdown list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to populate values fetched from a database to a drop down list, using rails 3:

`@details` contains all the values from the database. While printing `@details.inspect` it displays in the web page as:

```
[<DeviceDetail DeviceID: 14448, No: 616">, <DeviceDetail DeviceID: 14448, No: 617">, <DeviceDetail DeviceID: 14448, No: 618">]........
```

In the loop I fetch the `No` details. How can I show `No` in a drop down list?

```
 <% @details.each do |d| %>    
    <%=d.No%>
    <% end %>
```

I added the following for displaying `No` in drop down list, but it's returning the error `undefined method name for DeviceDetail:0x390f3f0`. My database does not contain name filed, so what should I put in the `:name` field? The database table contains `no`, `deviceid`, `speed` and `time`.

```
 <% @details.each do |d| %>    
      <%=collection_select(:device_detail, d.No, @details, :id, :name) %>
        <% end %>
```

It this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this part of a form? Use the `select_tag`, and select the input option for the same.
Check out http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you will need to declare the instance variable `@details` in your `Device` controller.  It should look something like this:

controller/device.rb:

```
def show
  @details = Detail.all
end
```

Then, in your index and show pages, you can access that instance variable like this:

views/device/show.rb:

```
<% @details.each do |detail| %>
  <%= render detail %>
<% end %>
```

It should loop through each of your details and render each one.  If you only want to show the the "no" of details it should look like this:

```
<% @details.each do |detail| %>
  <%= detail.no %>
<% end %>
```

Or, if you're on the show page you could simply call the detail for that page like this:

```
<%= detail.no %>
```

Is this what you were asking?

Comment: no i only want to display the No filed from database in the dropdown list